# connect to MongoDB 3.6 using dns seed list and java client

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to connect to mongo 3.6 using seed list  and java MongoClient (I cannot use the connection string method)

```
var serverAddress=new ServerAddress("mongodb+srv://myhost", 27017);
var client = new MongoClient(serverAddress);
```

The error I'm getting is :

> No server chosen by com.mongodb.Mongo$4@75c45c4b from cluster
>   description ClusterDescription

I've disable ssl to check , if that was an issue . it is not I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the URI approach to get the host for the dns seed list like so :

```
var uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb+srv://myhost:27017");


mongoClient = new MongoClient(getAddress(uri.getHosts()));

List<ServerAddress> getAddress(List<String> hosts) {
    List<ServerAddress> mongoServers = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
    for (var host : hosts) {
      mongoServers.add(new ServerAddress(host));
    }
  return mongoServers;  
}
```